# How to move cells to the top of a JPanel using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I'm creating a GUI interface which uses several `JPanels` all formatted using BorderLayout. My east and west panels utilize a `GridBagLayout`. I want my west panel to align towards the top of the JPanel to line up with my east panel, but for whatever reason it's stuck in the center, making the interface look kind of silly. I'm brand new to `GridBagLayout` and it seems far more complicated than any of the other layouts i've used in the past, so i'm having trouble getting this to work.

I've read tons on the Layout both here and on other sites, so I can't figure out why it won't behave like I want it to. From what I understand, using the `anchor()` method allows you to align your widgets within the layout. My west panel uses a `JLabel` with some `JRadioButtons`, which I have anchored at `NORTHWEST` so the RadioButtons line up correctly and aren't scattered unevenly throughout.

Anyways, here is my code for both the east and west panels:

EAST(which i'm trying to align my west panel with):

```
//east panel
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

        eastLbl = new JLabel("Click to Complete", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        eastLbl.setFont(f3);
        eastLbl.setOpaque(true);
        eastLbl.setBackground(newOrange);
        eastLbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,100));
        eastLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        gbc1.weightx = 1;
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        eastPanel.add(eastLbl, gbc1);

        cartBtn = new JButton("Add to Cart");
        cartBtn.setFont(f3);
        cartBtn.setToolTipText("Add to cart");
        cartBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        cartBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,100));
        gbc1.weightx = 1;
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        eastPanel.add(cartBtn, gbc1);

        clearBtn = new JButton("Clear Order");
        clearBtn.setFont(f3);
        clearBtn.setToolTipText("Clear Order");
        clearBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        clearBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,100));
        gbc1.weightx = 1;
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 2;
        eastPanel.add(clearBtn, gbc1);

        exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
        exitBtn.setFont(f3);
        exitBtn.setToolTipText("Exit");
        exitBtn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        exitBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,100));
        gbc1.weightx = 1;
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 3;
        eastPanel.add(exitBtn, gbc1);

        c.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

WEST(which is stuck in the center of my JPanel, and is unevenly matched with my east panel):

```
//west panel
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

        westLbl = new JLabel("Click Seat Selection", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        westLbl.setFont(f3);
        westLbl.setOpaque(true);
        westLbl.setBackground(newOrange);
        westLbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,100));
        westLbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        gbc2.weightx = 1;
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 0;
        westPanel.add(westLbl, gbc2);

        lowerDeck = new JRadioButton("Lower Deck");
        gbc2.weightx = 2;
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 1;
        westPanel.add(lowerDeck, gbc2);

        upperDeck = new JRadioButton("Upper Deck");
        gbc2.weightx = 2;
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 2;
        westPanel.add(upperDeck, gbc2);

        obstructed = new JRadioButton("Obstructed View");
        gbc2.weightx = 2;
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 3;
        westPanel.add(obstructed, gbc2);

        luxury = new JRadioButton("Luxury");
        gbc2.weightx = 2;
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 4;
        westPanel.add(luxury, gbc2);

        bGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        bGroup.add(lowerDeck);
        bGroup.add(upperDeck);
        bGroup.add(obstructed);
        bGroup.add(luxury);

        c.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

To reiterate, my east panel flows from the top of the panel to the bottom, while my west panel sits in the center. Both use `GridBagLayout`. I want them to align properly from the top of each `JPanel`. I'm sure i'm making a silly mistake, but i'm at wits end with it and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks again folks :)

Comment: By default `GridBagLayout` will layout out components from the center of the container. Make the last component/row take up the remaining vertical space by setting the `gridy` constraint to 1

Comment: Wouldn't that over write my topmost JLabel though?

Comment: That depends on how you setup the layout...